# How to get the json object in our rest java controller,for example we have a search method with multiple parameters

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc, jersey-2.0, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

Example:- searchCriteria(jsonObject)

1.

```
 jsonObject :   { employeeId :"xx" , 
              employeeName : "yy",  
             employeeDOB : "zz", 
              }
```

2.

```
jsonObject :    { 
     SSN:"xx" 
}
```

3.

```
jsonObject : { agentId:"xx",
                  agentType: "yy"   
}
```

So basically, we want to build a custom search component(which can be reused for other search methods,only parameters will change) where we will pass `jsonObject` which may change according to point1,point2,point3.

Answer (score 0):

Jersey supports parsing values to Jettison JSONObject/JSONArray.

**Example:**

```
jsonObject :   { employeeId :"xx" , 
              employeeName : "yy",  
             employeeDOB : "zz", 
              }
```

**Code:**

```
@POST
@Path("/rest")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
public Object searchData(JSONObject json) {
  String empId = json.optString("employeeId");
  String empName = json.optString("employeeName");
  String empDOB = json.optString("employeeDOB");
  return new Object();
}
```

Similarly, you can implement your generic search to accept any object and extract the contents.